# Spring MVC routing in Google App Engine

Tags: spring, google-app-engine, spring-mvc

I'm trying to build a spring mvc web on google app engine. But I can't make the routing/mapping work.

I have my `HelloController`, which indicates that I want to map to `/hello`

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String Index() {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

and a very simple `hello.jsp` file

```
    <html>
  <head><title>Hello :: Spring Application</title></head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello - Spring Application</h1>
    <p>Greetings.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

however, when I try to access `/hello`, I will get 404 not found.

here is my xml mapping file `mvc-servlet.xml`

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.example.web" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

What am I missing ? How to fix it ?

Comment: did you map spring servlet in web.xml?

Comment: where did you put hello.jsp? I suppose you should put it in a directory specified by `prefix` in `InternalResourceViewResolver` config

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a web.xml ?

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

> ContextLoaderListener ties the ApplicationContext lifecycle to
>   ServletContext lifecycle and automate the creation of
>   ApplicationContext.  ApplicationContext is the place for Spring beans
>   and we can provide it’s configuration through contextConfigLocation
>   context parameter. root-context.xml file provides the configuration
>   details for WebApplicationContext.

Her eis a tutorial http://www.journaldev.com/2433/spring-mvc-tutorial-for-beginners-with-spring-tool-suite